# DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable keep on getting error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, inertiajs

I am trying to implement a dragdrop functionality in my code. Now I can choose a menu and drop it anywhere. Sometimes when I drag and drop one menu, another menu goes to another place. But I notice most of the times as I release it back, it's like redirecting to a blank white page and in the console, I saw error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`, which points to,

```
{menu.children.map((child) => (
                            <Draggable
                              key={child.id}
                              draggableId={child.id}
                              index={index}
                            >
```

Exactly on here, `draggableId={child.id}`

I really don't know how can I fix this ? I think there must be something wrong with the logic in my `onDragEnd function`. Any react please, please help

```
import { BiHomeAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import { AiOutlineUnorderedList } from "react-icons/ai";

import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

import NavLink from "../Link/NavLink";

export default function SideBarMenu({ isOpen, app }) {
    // Get params
    const { pathname } = window.location;
    const firstPath = pathname.split("/")[1];

    const [isParams, setIsParams] = useState(firstPath);

    const [appMenus, setAppMenus] = useState(app.menus);

        const onDragEnd = (result) => {
        const { destination, source } = result;

        // Check if there is a valid destination
        if (destination) {
            const { index: sourceIndex } = source;
            const { index: destinationIndex } = destination;

            // Perform the necessary logic based on the drag and drop result
            // For example, you can update the app.menus array with the new order

            // Create a copy of the menus array
            const updatedMenus = [...app.menus];

            // Remove the dragged item from the source index
            const [draggedItem] = updatedMenus[sourceIndex].children.splice(source.index, 1);

            // Insert the dragged item at the destination index
            updatedMenus[destinationIndex].children.splice(destination.index, 0, draggedItem);

            // Update the state with the new menus order
            setAppMenus(updatedMenus);
            }
        };
        
      return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
          <div
            className={`${
              isOpen ? "items-center" : " items-start"
            } flex flex-col space-y-3`}
          >
            <Droppable droppableId="sidebar-menu" direction="vertical">
              {(provided) => (
                <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                  {app.menus.map((menu, index) => {
                    if (isParams === "jualan") {
                      if (
                        menu.id === "tempahan" ||
                        menu.id === "laporan" ||
                        menu.id === "penyelenggaraan" ||
                        menu.id === "admin" ||
                        menu.id === "test"
                      ) {
                        return null; // skip this menu item
                      }
                    } else {
                      if (
                        menu.id === "jualan" ||
                        menu.id === "laporansales" ||
                        menu.id === "penyelenggaraansales"
                      ) {
                        return null; // skip this menu item
                      }
                    }
    
                    if (isParams === "pentadbir") {
                      if (
                        menu.id === "tempahan" ||
                        menu.id === "laporan" ||
                        menu.id === "penyelenggaraan" ||
                        menu.id === "jualan" ||
                        menu.id === "laporansales" ||
                        menu.id === "penyelenggaraansales"
                      ) {
                        return null; // skip this menu item
                      }
                    } else {
                      if (menu.id === "admin") {
                        return null; // skip this menu item
                      }
                    }
    
                    if (menu.children.length > 0) {
                      return (
                        <div
                          key={menu.id}
                          className={`${
                            isOpen ? "" : "w-[14.5rem] 2xl:w-[15rem]"
                          } `}
                        >
                          {menu.children.map((child) => (
                            <Draggable
                              key={child.id}
                              draggableId={child.id}
                              index={index}
                            >
                              {(provided) => (
                                <div
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                >
                                  <NavLink
                                    id={child.id}
                                    key={child.id}
                                    href={child.href}
                                    active={child.current}
                                    isOpen={isOpen}
                                  >
                                    <span
                                      className={`${
                                        child.current &&
                                        "text-primary-light"
                                      } text-slate-50`}
                                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                        __html: child.icon,
                                      }}
                                    />
                                    <span
                                      className={`${isOpen && "hidden"} 
                                            ${
                                              child.current &&
                                              "text-primary-light font-medium"
                                            }
                                            font-medium text-sm`}
                                    >
                                      {child.title}
                                    </span>
                                  </NavLink>
                                </div>
                              )}
                            </Draggable>
                          ))}
                        </div>
                      );
                    }
                  })}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          </div>
          </DragDropContext>
        )
}
```